# Append GridView From DataTable in C# Windows Application

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to append the data from database based on the combobox value using button click.

As of now, my code is as below:

```
private void LoadData()
    {
        try
        {
            string prdInfo = "SELECT product_name AS Description, unit_per_case AS Cases,     unit_price AS Rate FROM product_info " +
            "WHERE product_name='" + ComboBox1.Text+ "'";

            //create an OleDbDataAdapter
            OleDbDataAdapter datAdp = new OleDbDataAdapter(prdInfo, strCon);

            //create a DataTable to hold the query results
            DataTable dTable = new DataTable();

            //fill the DataTable
            datAdp.Fill(dTable);

            //set DataSource of DataGrid 
            datGrid.DataSource = dTable;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
```

It's just adding single row and not append the next value that i select.

I need to append in GridView based on the value from combo box for each button click.

Can any one please help?

Comment: Don't create a new Data Table each time you load data. Creating a new Data Table clears out previous data.

Comment: I agree, so where should i define this Data Table?

Comment: You can still use it in LoadData. But declare it outside of the method as a property of the class.

Comment: Thanks, but am getting NullException for DataTable. Am i doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have add DataTable value as Null in global and added the below code:

```
if (dtData == null)
            {
                //set DataSource of DataGrid
                dtData = dTable.Copy();
                datGrid.DataSource = dtData;
            }
            else
            {
                dtData.BeginLoadData();
                foreach (DataRow row in dTable.Rows)
                    dtData.LoadDataRow(row.ItemArray, true);
                dtData.EndLoadData();

            }
```

It's working fine now. Thanks MikeG for your assistance..

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try the `Merge()` method.

```
table1.Merge(table2);
```

You can take the complete example from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk68ew7b(v=vs.110).aspx).